Fedora Server 40 systemd doesn't work with podman container unit
Here the details:
I wrote a systemd unit working on Fedora Workstation. The unit is stored in "~/.config/containers/systemd".
Both if I store the same unit source in that path or in "~/.config/systemd/users" on Fedora Server, doesn't work. It's not able to read the "[Container]" section.
Why this difference between these two distros?
Here the source:
[Unit]
After=network-online.target

[Container]
ContainerName=syncthing

UserNS=keep-id
HostName=host-syncthing
Image=docker.io/syncthing/syncthing:latest
PublishPort=xx:xx
PublishPort=xx:xx/tcp
PublishPort=xx:xx/udp
PublishPort=xx:xx/udp
Volume=%h/syncthing:/var/syncthing:z

[Service]
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

Thank you
